# Jquerymobile mobile.Changepage transition: someVariable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have a jquerymobile code for changing the pages with swipe function. My mobile.changePage looks lik this:

> $.mobile.changePage("#page"+window.now, {transition:
>   "slide"}, false, true);

I am also using localStorage to store settings. I have loaded them to variable transitionSettings:

> function loadSettings(){
>       var transitionSettings = window.localStorage.getItem("transitionsSettings");}

The *transitionsSettings* variable can be 'slide' or 'none'.

I want to insert this string to my *mobile.changePage* so it would load settings and set the right transition.

I have tried **{transition: transitionSettings}** and also **{transition: +transitionSettings}** but it didn't work. However, my *loadSettings()* function is in a **.js** file called *settings.js* and my **mobile.changePage()** is in *slide.js* and both of them are imported to *index.html*

I think *slide.js* should access *settings.js* variables with no problem. But this is not working and the whole swipe functionality is broken by this.

**Any suggestions on how to import settings variable to transition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store the transitionSettings variable in a global variable that can be accessed anywhere in your code, you can achieve a [global var in javascript](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable) by attaching any var to the window object, so in your example, you could change loadSettings() function to this:

```
function loadSettings(){ var window.transitionSettings = window.localStorage.getItem("transitionsSettings");}
```

and use it in slide.js like so:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page"+window.now, {transition: window.transitionSettings}, false, true);
```

that should work fine..

Also you could probably just get your setting right from slide.js, like so:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page"+window.now, {transition: window.localStorage.getItem("transitionsSettings")}, false, true);
```

That should also work fine..

Comment: thank you so much. I have used your last suggestion and it worked perfectly. Havent tested first suggestion but I think it would work too.